# How can I write the equation 9 x == 5 y + 8 z + 27 in the form 9x - 5y - 8z - 27=0?

Tags: output-formatting

I use

```
myeq = CoplanarPoints[{{7, 4, 2}, {8, 1, 5}, {9, 6, 3}, {x, y, z}}]
```

> 9 x == 27 + 5 y + 8 z

I am trying to write `myeq` in the form $9x-5y-8z-27 = 0$. I tried

```
TraditionalForm[myeq]
```

or

```
PolynomialForm[myeq]
```

and

```
PolynomialForm[myeq, TraditionalOrder -> True]
```

I can not get the form $9x-5y-8z-27=0$.

How can I write the equation `9 x == 5 y + 8 z + 27` in the form 9x - 5y - 8z - 27 = 0?

Comment: `TraditionalForm[Subtract@@myeq == 0]`?

Comment: Your method is true for my question. But this is not true
`myeq = CoplanarPoints[{{7, 4, 2}, {8, 1, 5}, {9, 3, 6}, {x, y, z}}];
TraditionalForm[Subtract @@ myeq == 0]`

Comment: `SubtractSides[myeq]` or if you prefer `SubtractSides[Reverse@myeq]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way using `ReplaceAll`:

```
TraditionalForm[myeq /. a_ == b_ :>ExpandAll[a - b] == 0]

(*9 x-5 y-8 z-27==0*)
```

The second example:

```
myeq = CoplanarPoints[{{7, 4, 2}, {8, 1, 5}, {9, 3, 6}, {x, y, z}}];

TraditionalForm[myeq /. a_ == b_ :>ExpandAll[a - b] == 0]

(*9 x-2 y-5 z-45==0*)
```

Comment: This is not true when I use your code
`myeq = CoplanarPoints[{{7, 4, 2}, {8, 1, 5}, {9, 3, 6}, {x, y, z}}];
TraditionalForm[myeq /. a_ == b_ :> a - b == 0]`

Comment: I tried
`myeq = Expand[
   CoplanarPoints[{{7, 4, 2}, {8, 1, 5}, {9, 3, 6}, {x, y, z}}]];
TraditionalForm[myeq /. a_ == b_ :> a - b == 0]`
it works.

Answer (score 11):

`SubtractSides` was added some versions back for this common operation. Combine with `ExpandAll` if you want it expanded:

```
eqn = CoplanarPoints[{{7, 4, 2}, {8, 1, 5}, {9, 3, 6}, {x, y, z}}]

(* 9 x == 2 y + 5 (9 + z) *)

ExpandAll@SubtractSides@eqn

(* -45 + 9 x - 2 y - 5 z == 0 *)
```

If you really want fine control over output formatting, you might want to break down the equation algebraically and use boxes for the output:

```
Flatten@Reverse[
    {1, {x, y, z}} CoefficientArrays[eqn, {x, y, z}]] // 
  DeleteCases[0] // Replace[{
   List[a__] :> RawBoxes@MakeBoxes[Plus[a] == 0, StandardForm],
   List[] :> True}]

(* 9 x - 2 y - 5 z - 45 == 0 *)
```

`List[]` can occur if everything in the equation cancels out. Of course, if `TraditionalForm` work for you, it's easier than boxes. In a simple `Defer` works, too:

```
Flatten@Reverse[
    {1, {x, y, z}} CoefficientArrays[eqn, {x, y, z}]] // 
  DeleteCases[0] // Replace[{
   List[a__] :> Defer[Plus[a] == 0],
   List[] :> True}]

(* 9 x - 2 y - 5 z - 45 == 0 *)
```

Comment: I use
`eqn = CoplanarPoints[{{7, 4, 2}, {8, 1, 5}, {9, 3, 6}, {x, y, z}}];
TraditionalForm@ExpandAll@SubtractSides@eqn`
It works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

I use two functions for this sort of thing:

```
lhs[eq_Equal] := Expand[eq[[1]]]
rhs[eq_Equal] := Expand[eq[[2]] ]
```

### Example 1

```
myeq=CoplanarPoints[{{7,4,2},{8,1,5},{9,6,3},{x,y,z}}];
myeq = lhs[myeq] - rhs[myeq] == 0;
TraditionalForm[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Example 2

```
myeq = CoplanarPoints[{{7, 4, 2}, {8, 1, 5}, {9, 3, 6}, {x, y, z}}] 
TraditionalForm[lhs[myeq] - rhs[myeq] == 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I prefer `rhs` and `lhs` since it is more explicit and more clear for me than other methods (even though other methods might require less typing).

Comment: With your Example 2, I only get `9 x == 2 y + 5 (9 + z)`. I have to add 
`myeq = CoplanarPoints[{{7, 4, 2}, {8, 1, 5}, {9, 3, 6}, {x, y, z}}];
TraditionalForm[Expand[lhs[myeq] - rhs[myeq]] == 0]`

Comment: @ThuyNguyen This is strange. in my V 13.3.1 it works as is. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnRqA.png)  make sure to use the updated code with the Expand in it.

Comment: @ThuyNguyen which version of Mathematica are you using? Try from clean kernel if you have not done this.

Comment: Old version. I try that. Thanks again.

Comment: With your Example 2, I get the same your result without using `Expand`

Answer (score 4):

One simple method is using `SubtractSides` or `AddSides`

```
eq = 9 x == 5 y + 8 z + 27;
eqZeroForm = SubtractSides[eq, Last[eq]]
eqZeroForm1 = SubtractSides[eq, First[eq]]
eqZeroForm2 = AddSides[eq, -First[eq]]
eqZeroForm3 = AddSides[eq, -Last[eq]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
myeq = CoplanarPoints[{{7, 4, 2}, {8, 1, 5}, {9, 6, 3}, {x, y, z}}]
```

9 x == 27 + 5 y + 8 z

```
(myeq /. Equal :> Subtract) == 0
```

-27 + 9 x - 5 y - 8 z == 0